# Incorrect values with lag/row_number for generating column_name, old_value and new_value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a legacy audit table which is being referred by multiple reports across the organization and has data as follows:

| AUDIT_ENTRY_ID | Table_ID | Name | Service | Created_On | Updated_On |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FOO | Simple | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | FOO | Simpler | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 | 2022-12-31 12:05:00 |

I'm trying to create an audit view with column names, old values and new values.

The newly created rows will have the OLD_VALUE as NULL and the inserted value as NEW_VALUE.

While for updated rows the difference between the rows are to be added. (Refer to 5th row in the following table)

The expected output should be:

| AUDIT_ENTRY_ID | Table_ID | COLUMN_NAME | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE | UPDATED_ON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Name | NULL | FOO | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | Service | NULL | Simple | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | Created_On | NULL | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | Updated_On | NULL | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 | 2022-12-31 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | Service | Simple | Simpler | 2022-12-31 12:05:00 |

I tried the following SQL which is working for a single column but when a UNION ALL with multiple columns is done then due to difference in the column's data types the following error occurs:

> Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.

```
SELECT ID,
       Table_ID,
       'Service' AS COLUMN_NAME,
       CASE WHEN New IS NULL OR Old <> New THEN Old WHEN Old = New THEN NULL END AS [OLD_VALUE],
       CASE WHEN Old IS NULL OR Old <> New THEN New WHEN Old = New THEN NULL END AS [NEW_VALUE],
       Updated_On
FROM (SELECT A.audit_entry_id AS [ID],
             A.Table_ID,
             A.[Service] AS [New],
             A.[Updated_On],
             LAG(A.[Service]) OVER (PARTITION BY A.Table_ID ORDER BY A.audit_entry_id) AS [Old]
      FROM Aud_Table A) Audit_View
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       Table_ID,
       'Name' AS COLUMN_NAME,
       CASE WHEN New IS NULL OR Old <> New THEN Old WHEN Old = New THEN NULL END AS [OLD_VALUE],
       CASE WHEN Old IS NULL OR Old <> New THEN New WHEN Old = New THEN NULL END AS [NEW_VALUE],
       Updated_On
FROM (SELECT A.audit_entry_id AS [ID],
             A.Table_ID,
             A.[Name] AS [New],
             A.[Updated_On],
             LAG(A.[Name]) OVER (PARTITION BY A.Table_ID ORDER BY A.audit_entry_id) AS [Old]
      FROM Aud_Table A) Audit_View;
```

Other approach I tried with CTE also failed:

```
WITH audit_table AS
    (SELECT audit_entry_id AS [ID],
            Table_ID,
            Name,
            Created_On,
            Updated_On,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Table_ID ORDER BY AUDIT_ENTRY_ID) AS RN
     FROM Aud_Table)
SELECT O.ID,
       O.Table_ID,
       'Name' AS [COLUMN_NAME],
       CASE WHEN N.Name IS NULL OR O.Name <> N.Name THEN O.Name WHEN O.Name = N.Name THEN NULL END AS [OLD_VALUE],
       CASE WHEN O.Name IS NULL OR O.Name <> N.Name THEN N.Name WHEN O.Name = N.Name THEN NULL END AS [NEW_VALUE]
FROM audit_table O
     LEFT JOIN audit_table N ON O.Table_ID = N.Table_ID
                            AND O.RN - 1 = N.RN
UNION ALL
SELECT O.ID,
       O.Table_ID,
       'Created_On' AS [COLUMN_NAME],
       CASE
            WHEN N.Created_On IS NULL
              OR O.Created_On <> N.Created_On THEN O.Created_On
            WHEN O.Created_On = N.Created_On THEN NULL
       END AS [OLD_VALUE],
       CASE
            WHEN O.Created_On IS NULL
              OR O.Created_On <> N.Created_On THEN N.Created_On
            WHEN O.Created_On = N.Created_On THEN NULL
       END AS [NEW_VALUE]
FROM audit_table O
     LEFT JOIN audit_table N ON O.Table_ID = N.Table_ID
                            AND O.RN - 1 = N.RN;
```

Comment: I *strongly* suggest getting into the good habit of formatting your text. All left alligned code, for example, is very difficult to read and makes distinguishing specific blocks are code, such as where a CTE starts and ends, or what is your `SELECT` and what is your `FROM`, very difficult to tell apart. I've added some formatting for you, but get into the habit of doing this yourself; you'll find that others will be much more willing to help you if you present your code well.

Answer (score 1):

Both your solutions sound ok in concept (either use lag() or row_number with self left join on previous).
However, how you go and implement them with `UNION`s and long `CASE`s seems messy to me.

Just unpivot with cross apply.
Also throw some conversion to nvarchar to avoid the type difference errors. I haven't tested the following, but it should at least guide you:

```
--your CTE unchanged
;WITH audit_table AS
    (SELECT audit_entry_id AS [ID],
            Table_ID,
            Name,
            Created_On,
            Updated_On,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Table_ID ORDER BY AUDIT_ENTRY_ID) AS RN
     FROM Aud_Table)
select cur.ID,cur.Table_ID,unpivot_tb.*,cur.Updated_on
from
    audit_table as cur
    left join audit_table as prev on cur.Table_ID=prev.Table_ID and cur.RN=prev.RN+1
    cross apply(values
         ('Name'      ,convert(nvarchar(200),prev.Name      ),convert(nvarchar(200),cur.Name      ))
        ,('Service'   ,convert(nvarchar(200),prev.[Service] ),convert(nvarchar(200),cur.[Service] ))
        ,('Created_on',convert(nvarchar(200),prev.Created_on),convert(nvarchar(200),cur.Created_on))
        ,('Updated_on',convert(nvarchar(200),prev.Updated_on),convert(nvarchar(200),cur.Updated_on))
    ) as unpivot_tb(COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! Although this returns all the unmodified columns as well with `NULL` in OLD_VALUE and NEW_VALE. If I exclude with `WHERE OLD_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND NEW_VALUE IS NOT NULL` then the output is incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean you don't want to see columns where the values stayed the same? Just add a `where unpivot_tb.OLD_VALUE <> unpivot_tb.NEW_VALUE` at the end